# How to only run php code when text is in input box

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I have a database that I am searching and displaying results from, each php query is in its own file being called by using require_once(ect) in the body.

They are all linked to the same submit button but I would like to only run the one that has text entered into it.

So I have 4 search box's each with there own file like this, which just searches a different column in the database.

I am wanting to only display 'no results found' or the amount of results found if the user has typed anything into that search box and submitted.

What is happening is the code is working but i get the other 3 'no results found' from the other files even though the user has not tried to search in that field.

I feel like there is an easy solution but I just cant figure it out, thanks in advance.

```
<?php

$stmtArtist = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT artist, genre, event, venue, eventdate FROM events WHERE artist = ?");
$stmtArtist->bind_param('s', $_GET['searchArtist']);
$stmtArtist->execute(); 
$stmtArtist->bind_result($artist, $genre, $event, $venue, $eventdate); 
$stmtArtist->store_result();
$numRows = $stmtArtist->num_rows;

if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {

    if ($numRows <= 0) {

        echo "no results found!";

    } else {

        echo "$numRows "." results found";

        while ($stmtArtist->fetch()) { 
            $timestampDate = strtotime($eventdate);
            $displayDate = date("D d M Y", $timestampDate);

            echo "<table border=1>"; 
            echo "<tr> <th>Artist</th> <th>Genre</th> <th>Venue</th> <th>Date</th> <th>Event</th> </tr>";
            echo "<tr> <td>$artist</td> <td>$genre</td> <td>$venue</td> <td>$eventdate</td> <td>$event</td></tr>";
            echo "</table>";

        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Use `empty()` and maybe even `isset()` on your textarea POST var.

Comment: please don't use snippets with PHP this is useless. We don't see what you see

Comment: @SuperDJ I've removed the snippet. I think it's Stack's new feature method in order to make sure that an OP who doesn't have experience indenting code for a properly formatted question, is well indented. Stack will need to improve on that feature.

Comment: @fred -ii- do I sense a meta post here?

Comment: @DarylGill I wanted to, but you know... they'd just shoot me down like a WWII Stuka. The snippets do have their pros as they do their cons. I'm leaning more towards the cons, just ever so slightly.

Comment: @Fred-ii- You never know. if you use a complex structure of puppy dog eyes, smiley faces and a more complex structure of nice words.. You may be accepted into the world of meta

Comment: @DarylGill You have a point there. Maybe "Cocker Spaniel" type of "puppy eyes"? Those "always" work lol - I was actually thinking about that earlier as to how I would formulate such a post, including getting a few of my Stack friends in on it, in order to get other people's opinions.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Avoid lolcats and you'll possibly see me making an appearance, if i'm around that is

Comment: @DarylGill You've got yourself a deal ;) *shake on it*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to actually process the form when you have submitted and it has entered a value:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['submit']) && !empty($_GET['searchArtist'])) {

    $stmtArtist = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT artist, genre, event, venue, eventdate FROM events WHERE artist = ?");
    $stmtArtist->bind_param('s', $_GET['searchArtist']);
    $stmtArtist->execute(); 
    $stmtArtist->bind_result($artist, $genre, $event, $venue, $eventdate); 
    $stmtArtist->store_result();

    $numRows = $stmtArtist->num_rows;

    if ($numRows <= 0) {
        echo "no results found!";
    } else {
        echo "$numRows results found <br/>";

        echo "<table border=1>"; 
        echo "<tr> <th>Artist</th> <th>Genre</th> <th>Venue</th> <th>Date</th> <th>Event</th> </tr>";
        while ($stmtArtist->fetch()) { 

            $timestampDate = strtotime($eventdate);
            $displayDate = date("D d M Y", $timestampDate);

            echo "<tr> <td>$artist</td> <td>$genre</td> <td>$venue</td> <td>$eventdate</td> <td>$event</td></tr>";

        }
        echo "</table>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: *Hm,* I'd go more with an `!empty()` for `searchArtist` in conjunction with an `isset()` just to be sure.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yeah better idea, since you'll take up values in there

Comment: I usually like to use `empty()`, as using `isset()` IMO, doesn't check if something was entered or not. +1 ;)

Comment: @Fred-ii- yeah, `isset($_GET['submit'], $_GET['searchArtist'])` is still true on `?submit=&searchArtist=` which should be false

Comment: This works a treat, plus I understand it aswell. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @James im glad this helped, credit goes to Fred as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) instead, it does [both](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) isset (checks if variable/index is set) and checks if string is empty or not, and I've heard it's actually faster then isset too... You also want to make sure that the user input is sane/sanitize it. I just called a function here called "sane", you must write it yourself.

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['submit']) && !empty($_GET['searchArtist']) && sane($_GET['searchArtist'])) {
    $stmtArtist = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT artist, genre, event, venue, eventdate FROM events WHERE artist = ?");
    $stmtArtist->bind_param('s', $_GET['searchArtist']);
    $stmtArtist->execute(); 
    $stmtArtist->bind_result($artist, $genre, $event, $venue, $eventdate); 
    $stmtArtist->store_result();
    $numRows = $stmtArtist->num_rows;
    if ($numRows <= 0) {
        echo "no results found!";
    } else{
        echo "$numRows "." results found";
        while ($stmtArtist->fetch()) { 
            $timestampDate = strtotime($eventdate);
            $displayDate = date("D d M Y", $timestampDate);
            echo "<table border=1>"; 
            echo "<tr> <th>Artist</th> <th>Genre</th> <th>Venue</th> <th>Date</th> <th>Event</th> </tr>";
            echo "<tr> <td>$artist</td> <td>$genre</td> <td>$venue</td> <td>$eventdate</td> <td>$event</td></tr>";
            echo "</table>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Using `if (!empty($_GET['submit']))` doesn't make sense. OP wants to check if something is entered in textarea or not. The submit will always remain "not empty" when executed. Therefore it's best to use `isset()` on the submit button and an `!empty()` on the textarea, even checking if it is set also.

Comment: It's not a question of me being happy, it's just the way PHP works. Also, this `sane($_GET` - what is that? `sane()` isn't a core PHP function.

Comment: "You also want to make sure that the user input is sane/sanitize it. I just called a function here called "sane", you must write it yourself."